# Initialize an array in a struct

Tags: c++

Is there already a way where I can initialize an array **directly** in a struct? Like this:

```
struct S
{
  int arr[50] = {5};  
}
```

I know this only initializes the first element of the array, but is there any way to write something similar with **g++** but that can initialize all elements of the array with 5?

I've read that with **gcc** we can use designated intializers `int arr[50] = {[0 ... 49] = 5};` but this won't be possible in C++.

Comment: Why not use a constructor?

Comment: It's a long story. I'm just asking if it's possible

Comment: It is possible by providing your own constructor. You'd need to explain why (you think) that is not good enough if you want a different answer

Comment: Can you please give me an example how is it possible by providing my own constructor

Comment: "Creative" alternative: `struct S { std::array<int, 50> arr = []{ decltype(arr) rv; rv.fill(5); return rv; }(); };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `struct` object needs to have its constructor called when being initialized you can just perform this assignment inside the constructor, e.g.:

```
struct S
{
  int arr[50];  
  S() {
    for (int& val : arr) val = 5;
  }
};
```

Or similarly you can use `std::fill` from the `algorithm` header

```
#include <algorithm>
struct S
{
  int arr[50];  
  S() {
    std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 5);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yup - I believe [std::fill()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) is exactly what the OP looking for :)